# JQuery definition at angular2-webpack-starter

Tags: angular, webpack-2

I have index page with added scripts:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
      ...

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="/assets/scripts/resize.js"></script>
```

All these scripts need JQuery

I added JQuery with `npm install jquery`

But when my index page loading I gets:

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
```

and

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at resize.js:3
```

After loading process I checked in a browser console Jquery and noticed that I am able to use $('...')

So why scripts defined at the header don't see Jquery installed by `npm install jquery` and how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ProvidePlugin. https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/
Add this lines to your webpack config:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        $: 'jquery',
        jquery: 'jquery'
    })
]
```